# Inside mounted hinge for outward opening gate

Tags: hinges, gates

I have a bit of an odd gate mounting problem.

I need to install an outward opening 'side gate' but I do not want to mount the hinges on the outside of the gate (partly for security and partly because the gate has recessed cladding and so fitting T-hinges, hook and band hinges or similar would require packing behind the band which feels a bit of a 'bodge'.

The gate cannot open inwards due to a ramp behind the gate.

The picture below illustrates the problem (top/plan view):

[image]

- The first example shows the gate opening inwards with a typical hook and band type hinge - but I cannot install the gate opening inwards.
- The second example shows the gate opening outwards with a typical hook and band type hinge, but this has security issues and requires the band being packed behind which I do not want to do.
- The third example would partly solve the security concerns, but still has the band on the outside.
- The fourth example would seem to be a solution, but does this type of hinge exist? I cannot find anything like this anywhere. (The gate is 70mm thick)

If the fourth hinge type does not exist, can anyone suggest any other way of installing the gate?

The closest thing I have been able to find to the hinge type in the fourth example is a two-way hinge like this one https://www.amazon.co.uk/UHPPOTE-Stainless-Freegate-Two-way-Opening/dp/B01N4L5W13 though it is effectively a butt hinge again and I don't want/need to the two way opening.

I have been advised that butt hinges are absolutely not recommended for gates as they are not strong enough - though we have a very heavy, solid wood front door that is easily as heavy as this gate, that is fitted with butt hinges.

Surely there must be a way...

Comment: If you could have a metal shop fabricate a pair of top and bottom pivot hinges, those would work best. The only ones I could find on line to do what you want required a 3" gap at the post to the gate... https://www.hardwaresource.com/heavy-duty-bolt-on-hinge-7-12.html

Comment: You've indicated that you don't want the hinge showing on the outside, however that may be your best bet. To avoid the security issue of someone simply unscrewing the hinge to take the gate down, you use a carriage bolt. It has a domed head with no method of holding it in place, but a squared shoulder that goes into the hole in the gate. This square shoulder is what prevents the bolt from spinning when you tighten the nut from the inside. You may not want to shim out the gate for the hinge to meet up with it (I presume that's what "packing" means), but it might be your only choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 configurations, you just have to find one or fabricate one. One style looks like 2 pairs of scissors joined together. Look at the hood hinge of full-size automobiles. The action provides extra movement. This style can be found in some cabinet hinges for fully recessed doors. The second style is like a strap hinge with a curve in the long piece. Look at the trunk hinge in full-size automobiles. The hinge pin is inside but the curved strap gives clearance for the gate post.

Comment: These two hinge types would have done the job, but in the end I went for the gate opening inwards and just cut it short to avoid the ramp. Not the perfect solution, but the hinges in this answer would also have been a compromise to some extent because of their bulk. I've accepted this answer, though, as it best fulfils the original question requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Where there's a will there's a way.. You could use any ordinary hinge and modify it. As hinges are often made of steel, it would be easy to weld additional material to the hinge plates to create the shape of figure 4.